# mailto not working in android cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am using followinfg code to ope default mail client in my cordova app.

```
document.location.href = "mailto:contact@test.com";
```

I have added follwing code in my config file:

```
<access origin="*" />
  <access origin="tel:*" />
  <access origin="geo:*" />
  <access origin="mailto:*" />
  <access origin="sms:*" />
  <access origin="market:*" />
```

Its working fine on windows.

But, on android its giving following error:

```
GET mailto:contact@test.com net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Whats an issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<access origin="mailto:*" />
```

to

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```